# Applying flags in CMake environment

Tags: cmake

I am a newbie to cmake. I want to add a new flag to be applied for my module build which uses cmake as build tool. Am trying to add the flag in CMakeLists.txt but the changes are not reflected. Should I apply the changes to some other file? I tried cleaning using 
$ cmake clean .
but still the problem exists.

Request help.

Regards
Santosh

Comment: What do you mean by flag? A cmake variable? A compiler argument? A `#define`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean compiler flags then you can do something like below, note I am a newbie too so there might well be better ways:

```
   if( MSVC )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " /DWIN32 /W3 /GX /GR /Wp64 /Zc:forScope" )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG " /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /GZ /Gm /RTC1 /ZI" )
    elseif( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} " -ansi -Winvalid-pch" )
    endif()
```

Comment: you generally want to append to the flags so you don't clobber any flags the user or a higher up CMakeLists has set.